# How to return list of data to swift from objc?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, c++11

I have next code for implement callback that receice several values :

```
+(bool)select:(int)x0 y0:(int)y0 x1:(int)x1 y1:(int)y1{
    if (viewer == NULL)
        return false;
    std::function<void(std::string&)> callback = [](std::string& test) {
        std::cout<< test << std::endl;
    };
    viewer->activeViewportWrap().selectIOS(TghRmtVport::kSelSkipHighlighted|TghRmtVport::kSelHighlight,x0,y0,x1,y1);
    viewer->activeViewportWrap().getSelectedHandles(TghRmtVport::kSelSkipUnhighlighted, x0,y0,x1,y1,callback);
    return true;
}
```

This code implemented in mm file. How I can send data (`std::string& test`) from callback to Swift list?

**Edited**: I made mistake. Not to Swift list. To Swift array.I need to trasfer data of strign from C++ to Swift array of strings.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what do you mean by:

1. "Swift list"?
2. "send data (std::string& test)"

You will need Objective-C bridge between C++ and Swift code. However, from what you asked, it is completely unclear what exactly you need to marry.
Could you be more specific?